# accessing variable from parent class

Tags: java, class, parent

gameServer.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class gameServer{

    public static server server;
    public static gameRunner gameRunner;
    public static ArrayList<packet> packets = new ArrayList<packet>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        server = new server();
        server.startServer(5050);
        Runnable listenServer = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    packets.add(server.getPacket());
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(listenServer).start();
        gameRunner = new gameRunner();
        while(true) {
            if(packets.size() <= 0)
                continue;
            gameRunner.executeMessage(packets.get(0));
            packets.remove(0);
        }
    }
}
```

server.js:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class server {

    public static DatagramSocket socketServer;
    private Date date = new Date();

    public void startServer (int port) throws SocketException {
        socketServer = new DatagramSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Started Server on port: " + port);
    }
public void sendPacket (packet packet) {
        String message = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < packet.header.length; i++) {
            message += packet.header[i] + "\r\n";
        }
        message += "\r\n" + packet.message;
        String[] info = packet.address.split(":");
        try {
            sendPacket(message, (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName(info[0]), Integer.parseInt(info[1]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("failed to determine host");
        }
    }
```

}

gameRunner.js:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;


public class gameRunner {

    public static ArrayList<object> objects = new ArrayList<object>();
    public static player[] players = new player[1000];

    public Date date = new Date();

    Runnable updatePlayers = new Runnable() {
        public void run () {
            while(true) {
                long StartTime = date.getTime();
                for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    if(players[i] == null)
                        continue;
                    players[i].updatePos();
                }
                while(StartTime + 100 < date.getTime()) { }
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable sendPlayerPackets = new Runnable () {
        public void run () {
            while(true) {
                parent.gameServer.sendPacket(player[0].packet); //<<<----
                }
        }
    };

}
```

I am new to classes, abstract, inherent and such. I need to be able to access socketServer object in gameServer from gameRunner to send a message. I am not sure how to do this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT1 guessed right :)**

Some words on design:

- Most of these statics are horrible, you should only make properties static when they are part of the class such as default values, [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) business and when you are really drunk and lazy - but that's a different topic (you will get the hang of that if you keep coding)
- Actually you should not make properties public, they should always be private or protected, with a public getter/setter method - that way you can restrict access to the properties and can control what happens on a get or set. (but this tends to be very tedious in java)

Now, keeping with the statics you could easily send a message like this (in sendPlayerPackets.run()): `server.sendPacket(player[0].packet);`

To pass the server along to the gameRunner you would do:

(in gameRunner.java)

```
public class gameRunner {
  public static ArrayList<object> objects = new ArrayList<object>();
  public static player[] players = new player[1000];

  public server gameServer;

  /* ... */
  Runnable sendPlayerPackets = new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
        while(true) {
            gameServer.sendPacket(gameRunner.players[0].packet); //<<<----
            }
    }
};
```

and in gameServer.java:

```
public class gameServer{
  /* ... */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    /* ... */
    gameRunner = new gameRunner();
    gameRunner.gameServer = server;
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

**old part**

Purely on instinct I guess you want this:

```
public class A {
    public B foo;
    public C bar;

    public A() {
      // java does not like exposing this, but screw that
      foo = new B(this, 10);
      C = new C(this);
    }
}

public class B {
    private A parent;
    public int numB;

    public B(A parent, int num) {
      this.parent = parent;

      numB = num;
    }
}

public class C {
    private A parent;
    public int numC;

    public C(A parent) {
      this.parent = parent;

      if(parent != null && parent.B != null)
        numC = parent.B.numB;
    }
}
```

In short: you have to pass the parent to the child for it to be able to access it.

Note that in this example B has to be initialized before C, to get around this you would need events i guess. Anyways, the idea does not seem well defined, you should think about what you want to accomplish again (and tell us).

Answer (score 0):

```
int numB = A.bb.num;
```

should do it. However, it would be useful if you could describe what you are trying to accomplish, because having a static variable that is set by a constructor (which is what you are doing with `num` in `B`) is most likely not a good idea. Also, since you are using the word "parent", it sounds like you are intending to do inheritance, but the code example does not have any inheritance.

Comment: I am working on a gameserver and I have a "main" class with an object "UdpServer", and another "playerController", I want to use UdpServer's send function from object "playerController". "UdpServer" has an open UDP socket which is stuck to a port. So I cannot create a new instance of "UdpServer" I need to use the one in the "main" class.

Comment: @PatrickLorio: I think I understand - so `Main` (which corresponds to `A`) contains a static `UdpServer` (which corresponds to `B`), which you want to access from `playerController` (which is an instance of `C`)? You should have used the actual class names; that would have made your situation easier to understand. Then the code I showed should work. However, beware that static instances often make the code less testable; you should consider passing the `UdpServer` as a parameter to the `playerController` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Create a getter method, `getNum() { return num; }`, in B, and call `B.getNum()` in C. I am not sure where the reference to B comes in. C does not extend B, is that what you intend?